# Java passing same parameter to more than one function

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns

I want to do some calculations in different functions and i want to write clean code.

At first, i wrote something like this in service layer:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
public Report analyse(ExcelDto excel){
       method1(excel.getText());
       method2(excel.getText());
       method3(excel.getText());
       return  report;
    }
public void method1(String text) { }
public void method2(String text) { }
public void method3(String text) { }
public void method4(String text) { }
}
```

But then i thought i was repeating the code too much. Do you have any idea to make this code based on design patterns?

Comment: just adding here that side-effects are not really something you want from your code. it's very unclear how the Report is generated that is returned by `analyse` (I guess it's coming from the class?) - while it is certainly possible to use and chain different `void` methods (or Consumers as a subset of these) it's not advised for clean code unless you keep it mostly side-effect free.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have an ordered collection of `Consumer<String>` in your class and you want to invoke each of them in order using the same parameter.

An idea may be to create a method in your class that returns a `List<Consumer<String>>`, for example:

```
public List<Consumer<String>> consumers() {
    return List.of(
        this::method1,
        this::method2,
        this::method3,
        this::method4
    );
}
```

... and then the `analyse` method will simply loop through this list:

```
public Report analyse(ExcelDto excel) {
    //... missing code
    consumers().forEach(c -> c.accept(excel.getText()));
    return report;
}
```

Note: you may build the `consumers()` list dynamically by reflection, but you wouldn't be able to control the order of the methods and I don't know if that's important from your functional perspective.